# Magento 2 Indexing

Tags: magento

We have one Magento 2 project where we configured cron every min. Ideally the site has no change but still all cron jobs running too frequently.

Questions :

1. How Magento consider to re-run a index even there is no change.
2. Magento cron running synchronize or parallels way.
3. How to prevent run indexing if there is no change any lock or anything Magento manage ?

Answer (score 0):

If your indexer is **update by schedule**.
then only changed data will be reindexed not all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a schedule set for the crons. If you find that the frequency is too short, you can change the frequency of crons in a `crontab.xml` file.

You need to know the cron's name and its instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following link for configure cron time.

https://amasty.com/blog/configure-magento-cron-job/